# launch activity twice even with launchMode="singleTask"

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, launchmode

I have an activity for showing tour details with two inconsistent goals

**First**
that activity has a booking button which redirects to bank pay and get back to activity after successful or unsuccessful pay.that is why i set Launch Mode in manifest  to stop activity from re creating.

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

**Second**
that activity has a button which redirect to similar tour,then i have to call `finish();` before `startActivity()` to make intent work!

**`onNewIntent()` inside activity to get data of first part**

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (intent.getData() != null) {
        Helper.logDebug("fsfsfsgsgsgs", "inside get data not null");
        String query = intent.getData().getQuery();
        Helper.logDebug("fsfsfsgsgsgs","query is "+ query);
        if (query!=null && query.contains("Status=OK")) {
            if (frgBtmReserve!=null){
                frgBtmReserve.dismiss();
            }
            String count=query.substring(16);
            Helper.logDebug("fsfsfsgsgsgs","count is "+ count);
            frgObjectInfo.updateReserveCount(count);
            Helper.logDebug("fsfsfsgsgsgs", "inside status ok");
            Helper.notifyUserDone(getResources().getString(R.string.success_tour_reserve), this,R.drawable.ic_tick);
        } else {
            frgBtmReserve.dismiss();
            Helper.logDebug("fsfsfsgsgsgs", "inside status nok");
            Helper.notifyUserWarning(getResources().getString(R.string.error_tour_reserve), this);
        }
    }
}
```

**on click of second part** which should create new instance of current activity but it doesnt because of launch mode of activity which is `singleTask`.intent doesnt work until i `finish()` before `startActivity()`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityShowObject.class);
            intent.putExtra(ActivityShowObject.INTENT_KEY_TYPE, Obj.TYPE_TRAVEL);
            intent.putExtra(ActivityShowObject.INTENT_KEY_COLOR, color);
            intent.putExtra(ActivityShowObject.INTENT_KEY_OBJ_ID, obj.getAgencyId());
            ((AppCompatActivity)context).finish();
            startActivity(intent);
            Animatoo.animateShrink(context);
```

**that is my problem**
think of a user which is looking into some similar tours then press back and app goes back to the very first step! do you guys have a suggestion for me?

Comment: u need to show your code to let us understand the code!

Comment: i've added some of my code! is it helping? if not which part of my code is needed?

Comment: Using "singleTask" launchmode causes problems. How does the bank pay come back to your app?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of

`android:launchMode="singleTask"`

for a start. I think its the wrong usecase, making it harder for you.

You have two scenarios:

- 1) New activity pay for this tour
- 2) New activity Browse another tour

for #2 use the normal `startActivity` route, this will allow normal back navigation

for #1 you could also use normal `startActivity` but I have a feeling that when they pay successfully you do not want them to press back to go back to the tour, but if they are unsuccessful at paying you do want to allow them to go back?

If that is the case, you can use `startActivityForResult` when navigating to your #1 pay scenario.

When they complete payment successfully call

```
setResult(RESULT_OK)
```

if they are unsuccessful

```
setResult(RESULT_CANCELLED)
```

Then when they hit back, the result is propogated to the first activity, and you an use this to either call `finish()` or not.

Comment: thank you Blundell ! it sounds like a good solution. i have an idea after your answer,i will create a receipt activity which loads after successful or unsuccessful pay .receipt pay will have a button which navigate to my tours activity and back will navigate to tour info.in case of unsuccessful pay user automatically navigate to tour info activity... i will test this and tell you the result.